TrueNAS Scale Installation on Proxmox Fails with "lsblk: CANT_FIND_vda3_OR_vdap3: not a block device" Error
I'm attempting to install TrueNAS Scale (24.04.0) in Proxmox (8.2.2), but the installation fails with the error message lsblk: CANT_FIND_vda3_OR_vdap3: not a block device.
Below is the table of the Proxmox VM configuration:
| Component        | Type                 | Details                                              |
|------------------|----------------------|------------------------------------------------------|
| Memory           |                      | 32.00 GiB                                            |
| Processors       |                      | 4 (1 sockets, 4 cores) [kvm64,flags=+pdpe1gb] [numa=1]|
| BIOS             |                      | SeaBIOS                                              |
| Display          |                      | Default                                              |
| Machine          |                      | pc, iommu=virtio                                     |
| SCSI Controller  |                      | VirtIO SCSI                                          |
| CD/DVD Drive     | IDE2                 | local:iso/TrueNAS-SCALE-24.04.0.iso,media=cdrom,size=1588230K|
| Hard Disk (scsi1)| /dev/sdb             | size=7813993816K                                     |
| Hard Disk (scsi2)| /dev/sdc             | size=3906985816K                                     |
| Hard Disk (scsi3)| /dev/sdd             | size=3906985816K                                     |
| Hard Disk (scsi4)| /dev/sde             | size=3906985816K                                     |
| Hard Disk (scsi5)| /dev/sdf             | size=3906985816K                                     |
| Hard Disk (scsi6)| /dev/sdg             | size=3906985816K                                     |
| Hard Disk (virtio0)| local-lvm:vm-123-disk-1 | aio=io_uring,discard=on,iothread=1,size=64G |


During the installation, the option "Allow EFI Boot?" was answered with "NO."

What could be the issue in the VM disk configuration causing TrueNAS installation to fail on the virtio0 disk?

The solution is to boot in UEFI mode.
Changing the BIOS from SeaBIOS to OVMF (UEFI), then booting into the UEFI settings and disabling Secure Boot.
After rebooting, the TrueNAS installation should be able to proceed.

